# What is the opposite of "Boon"?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

If I grant someone a **Boon**, I am granting them a temporary positive effect. If I were to grant someone a temporary negative effect, what would an adequate word to describe that be?

I was initially drawn to **Bane**, as it's another four-letter B-word, with a negative connotation, but I'm not sure if the two terms are inherently equitable. Is this an appropriate usage of Bane? Is there a better word entirely?

Comment: Some quick answers can be found here: http://thesaurus.com/browse/boon

Comment: Quite apart from what thing they end up with, I would certainly advise against using the verb _grant_. Granting someone a bust/vice/nerf/whatever sounds most peculiar, like bestowing bankruptcy on someone, awarding them a headache, or conferring dishonour on them.

Comment: Just a side-note: A boon is not necessarily temporary. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you considered **drain**, **blight**, or **affliction**?

**Bane** seems okay to me, but I also like **drain** as in:

"The water was a **boon** to their morale, but the heat remained a **drain** on their physical state."

Comment: I like blight, especially for being another B

Comment: Mmm. Blight is good!

Answer (score 2):

In team-based videogames where support characters can provide these and their antitheses to other characters, they are usually referred to as 'buffs' [+] and 'nerfs' [-]. Personally, I think the word you are looking for is more like a *hindrance, penalty, handicap* or *weakness*. 'Bane' in that sense also works, as you said; [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/bane) gives us

```
[...] a thing that causes misery or distress [...]
```

I'm not sure how close that is to the context you're using, though. That may be too negative.

Comment: I'd actually refer to them as "Debuffs" in game. "Nerfs" are something that happen only in patch notes.

Comment: Fair point there. I guess that's the designer in me getting out. I don't suppose there's such a thing as a 'deboon' (not getting any hits for that or other prefixed terms like 'im- or unboon', ha). In addition to my suggestions, you could, however, use _impairment_ or _drawback_.

Answer (score 0):

In what context are you going to use the word?

I would say "to bestow a **curse** on someone", or "to **hex** someone"

Comment: I am hoping to use the term to categorize a group of related effects that are both negative in effect and posses a finite (and limited) duration. The latter criteria is why I'm leery of Curse, Hex, and Jinx.

Answer (score -1):

There's an expression, ***"Boon or Bust"*** that loosely means to hope for the boon or go bust trying.  This was used in the gold rush days of the old west (in the US).  In more modern times, it's more commonly known as "Boom or Bust" (though there are still many references to "Boon and Bust" or "Boon or Bust") and it's an economic concept, as defined in [this](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/b/boom-and-bust-cycle.asp) Investopedia article:

> Definition of 'Boom And Bust Cycle'
>
> A process of economic expansion and contraction that occurs repeatedly. The boom and bust cycle is a key characteristic of today’s capitalist economies. During the boom the economy grows, jobs are plentiful and the market brings high returns to investors. In the subsequent bust the economy shrinks, people lose their jobs and investors lose money. Boom-bust cycles last for varying lengths of time; they also vary in severity.

Comment: "Boom and bust" is preferred in the US, whereas "boon and bust" is primarily the European construction.

Comment: Actually, the historic term seems to be *boom*, not *boon*, as illustrated by this [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=boon+or+bust%2Cboom+or+bust&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cboon%20or%20bust%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cboom%20or%20bust%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Although this is a good general definition of "boon or bust" I don't feel like it answers the question, since Raven wanted "a temporary negative effect" and "putting a bust on" someone sounds completely wrong.

Comment: @bib, "boom or bust" is definitely the preferred expression based on the ngram but "boon or bust" is represented also, so it's known, just less used.

Comment: @jboneca, FWIW, I'm in the US and I know the expression as "boon or bust".

Comment: @KristinaLopez I didn't mean it as a challenge, just an observation from my time at an international bank where I noticed the difference in preference.

Comment: Boom or bust may have come out of the nuclear age … ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps **[demerit](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/demerit)**

> a fault or disadvantage

Comment: Isn't 'demerit' usually used to define a poor mark on a test (esp. driving) rather than a negative effect?

Comment: @NinjaDuckie It is often a negative mark used to determine punishment or negative outcomes (*Three demerits and you are suspended!*). I am not clear as to exactly what *temporary negative effect* means.

Answer (score -3):

How about a **vice**?

A vice is typically taken to mean a bad habit that is to one's own detriment, but given context, could mean anything that is to other's detriment.
For example as you might say:

> It was a real boon to us, that our new housemate Sally was a former top chef.

you could say:

> Jim's ongoing affliction became a real vice to us.

Comment: That's not sounding like a "vice", more like a detriment. Smoking's a vice, for example, so how is Jim's ongoing affliction the group's collective vice?